# Android studio error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android-studio

I was trying this code, it can build successfully but it crashes immediately.

The errors shows:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.logintest/com.example.logintest.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference.

And it said it is caused by :

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

I tried for a long time but still don't know how to fix it, any can help please, thanks!

The LoginActivity.java code are as follow:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public static final int GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_CODE = 10005;
        SignInButton signIn;
        GoogleSignInOptions gso;
        GoogleSignInClient signInClient;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            signIn.findViewById(R.id.signIn);
    
            gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
    
            signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);
            GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
            if(signInAccount != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
            }
    
            signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent sign = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(sign, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_CODE);
                }
            });
    
        }
       
    }
```

and the error code:

```
2021-05-28 21:37:33.617 10526-10526/com.example.logintest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.logintest, PID: 10526
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.logintest/com.example.logintest.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.logintest.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
```

part of activity_login.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">
   <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/signIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Have you provided `signIn` as Id in the layout also? The one you are referring as `R.id.signIn`.

Comment: I use <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton> in the activity_login.xml, i'm not sure if it is right to use it.

Comment: I add part of my .xml code about <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>, is it what you are talking about?

Comment: I change signIn.findViewById(R.id.signIn) to signIn=(SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.signIn) and it works! Thanks a lot!!